# Cannot change color of address bar or add favicon in mobile

Tags: colors, favicon, android-navigation-bar

I added

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#cc3333" />       
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="https://partyfavorz.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/2017-Logo-192.png">
```

to the header file in my child theme to change the color of the address bar in mobile and added the favicon sized at 192x192 but it will not display.

Could something be blocking it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the header file in my child theme has no effect. Adding it to to custom CSS section of my theme for the header does work. Problem solved.